# Positioning html CSS

Tags: html, css

I created a rectangle with a `position: relative;` and positioned an icon inside. But when I create a new div class called `.Home` and give it a `<h4>Home</h4>` element with `position: relative;` it position the element outside of the rectangle. What am I doing wrong?

I tried changing the position value but it doesn't work.

```css
.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  display: table;
  top: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  position: static;
}

.Rec {
  width: 97px;
  height: 812px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: relative;
}

.icons {
  position: relative;
  width: 38px;
  height: 48px;
  left: 30px;
  top: 29px;
}

.fa-bars {
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.Home {
  width: 65px;
  height: 29px;
  left: 34px;
  top: 217px;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  color: black;
  position: relative
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="Rec">
    <div class="icons"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      <div class="home">
        <h3>Home</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post the HTML that goes with this? I suspect, the `Home` element is a sibling of the `.Rec`, rather than a child

Comment: positioning can be tricky at first, here is a quick article that may help for the long run: https://medium.com/@jacobgreenaway12/taming-the-css-beast-master-positioning-5882bad14458

Comment: Hard to answer your question if we can't see the HTML.

Comment: <body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="Rec">
   <div class="icons"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i>

   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>

Comment: Sorry about that

Comment: In your CSS `Home` is capitalized, in your HTML it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need parent `div` to be `position:relative`.  Check out the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XoZpbb).

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="Rec">
    <div class="icons">
      <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      <div class="home">
        <h3>Home</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  display: table;
  top: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  position: static;
}

.Rec {
  width: 97px;
  height: 812px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: relative;
}

.icons {
  width: 38px;
  height: 48px;
  left: 30px;
  top: 29px;
}

.fa-bars {
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.home {
  width: 65px;
  height: 29px;
  left: 34px;
  top: 217px;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  color: black;
  position: relative;
}
```

Is this what you want?